# When have any error, application redirects to Error.cshtml.cs but doesn't show the cshtml page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

net core web application razor pages and I want to handle any internal Error and after the error I Save that Error in the database then show the Id of the error in the database in the Error.cshtml page, Actually it redirects to the Error.cshtml.cs (The backend of the razor page ) and successfully Save the Error in the database but unfortunately after that application just show me a page that says :This page isn’t workinglocalhost is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500 and the Url is : https://localhost:44386/Login?ReturnUrl=%2F
Here is the codes of my program.cs (startup) class about automatic Exception Handling :

```
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    //app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
```

And this is my Error.cshtml.cs the backend of Error page that application redirects to get method of it and saves the error successfully in the database but after that it doesn't show the cshtml page:

```
[ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
    [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
    public class ErrorModel : PageModel
    {
        public string? RequestId { get; set; }

        public bool ShowRequestId => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(RequestId);

        private readonly ILogger<ErrorModel> _logger;
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor;
        private readonly exceptionContext exceptionContext;

        public ErrorModel(ILogger<ErrorModel> logger,
            IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor,
            exceptionContext exceptionContext)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            this.contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
            this.exceptionContext = exceptionContext;
        }
        public Exception exceptionThatOccurred { get; set; }
        public ExceptionLog ExceptionInDb { get; set; }
        public long ExceptionInDbId { get; set; }

        public async Task OnGet()
        {
            var exceptionFeature = contextAccessor.HttpContext.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerPathFeature>();

            if (exceptionFeature != null)
            {
                // Get which route the exception occurred at
                string routeWhereExceptionOccurred = exceptionFeature.Path;

                // Get the exception that occurred
                exceptionThatOccurred = exceptionFeature.Error;
                try
                {
                    if (exceptionThatOccurred is not null)
                    {
                        ExceptionInDb = new ExceptionLog(exceptionThatOccurred,
                            exceptionThatOccurred.Message,exceptionThatOccurred.StackTrace
                            ,routeWhereExceptionOccurred);
                        await exceptionContext.Exceptions.AddAsync(ExceptionInDb);
                        await exceptionContext.SaveChangesAsync();
                        ExceptionInDbId = ExceptionInDb.Id;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        contextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Login");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    contextAccessor.HttpContext.Response.Redirect("/Login");
                }
                // TODO: Do something with the exception
                // Log it with Serilog?
                // Send an e-mail, text, fax, or carrier pidgeon?  Maybe all of the above?
                // Whatever you do, be careful to catch any exceptions, otherwise you'll end up with a blank page and throwing a 500
            }

            //RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;
        }
    }
```

and after it, if the try{} block was ok without any problem and not goes to the catch block, has to show this page (Error.cshtml) but unfortunately it cant :

```
@page
@model ErrorModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Error";
}

<h1 class="text-danger">Error.</h1>
<h2 class="text-danger">An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>
@if (Model.ExceptionInDbId != 0 && Model.ExceptionInDbId != null)
{
    <h1 style="color:red">خطایی رخ داده است، کد خطا: @Model.ExceptionInDbId</h1>
}
@*@if (Model.ShowRequestId)
{
    <p>
        <strong>Request ID:</strong> <code>@Model.RequestId</code>
    </p>
}*@

<h3>Development Mode</h3>
<p>
    Swapping to the <strong>Development</strong> environment displays detailed information about the error that occurred.
</p>
<p>
    <strong>The Development environment shouldn't be enabled for deployed applications.</strong>
    It can result in displaying sensitive information from exceptions to end users.
    For local debugging, enable the <strong>Development</strong> environment by setting the <strong>ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT</strong> environment variable to <strong>Development</strong>
    and restarting the app.
</p>
```

this is the whole of my program.cs class :

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddMvcOptions(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(typeof(UserActivityFilter));
});




builder.Services.AddScoped<IFileUploader, FileUploader>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IAuthHelper, AuthHelper>();
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IEmailService, EmailService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
var connectionString1 = builder.Configuration
    .GetConnectionString("RealState3");
var connectionString2 = builder.Configuration
    .GetConnectionString("RealState3Logs");
var connectionString3 = builder.Configuration
    .GetConnectionString("RealState3Exceptions");
AccountManagementBootstrapper.Configure(builder.Services,
    connectionString1);
LogManagementBootstrapper.Configure(builder.Services,
    connectionString2);
ExceptionManagementBootstrapper.Configure(builder.Services,
    connectionString3);

builder.Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
{
    options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
    options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Lax;
});
builder.Services.Configure<KestrelServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
});

// If using IIS:
builder.Services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
{
    options.AllowSynchronousIO = true;
});
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, o =>
    {
        o.LoginPath = new PathString("/Login");
        o.LogoutPath = new PathString("/Login");
        o.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/AccessDenied");
        o.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15);
    });
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("IsAdminOnly",
        policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new IsAdminRequirement()));
    options.AddPolicy("TokenVerifyOnly",
        policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new IsAdminRequirement()));
});
builder.Services.AddSingleton
             <IAuthorizationHandler, IsAdminRequirementHandler>();
builder.Services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
//builder.Services.AddRazorPages().AddMvcOptions(options =>
//{
//    options.Filters.Add(typeof(ExceptionFilter));
//});
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.



app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();


app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
app.UseHsts();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

could you please help me what can I do for it? thanks a lot.

Comment: **Do not** use `Response.Redirect` to perform a HTTP redirect in-event-of an error, and in fact: don't redirect at all: because a redirect in HTTP is a non-error condition. Instead, return HTTP 500 and use ASP.NET's ability to re-execute a request to return a custom error page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-7.0#exception-handler-page - see under `UseExceptionHandler`.

Comment: According to your description should it hit into catch block if so whats the scenario, can share a reproducible sample?

Comment: what do you mean ? if the error can't save in database for any reason. then the code goes to the catch block and it's redirected to login page

Comment: actually in the if block it doesn't use Response.Redirect it only use when the error is null

Comment: but unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: So my question is, when any error has been encountered does it saves in database?

Comment: Yes,Exactly ,first it saves in db